# I cannot send southbound commands via the context broker (Orion-LD)

Tags: fiware-orion

Service group provisioning:

```
curl -iX POST 'http://localhost:4041/iot/services' \
-H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "services": [
        {
            "apikey": "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
            "entity_type": "LightFixture",
            "resource": ""
        }
    ]
}'
```

Actuator provisioning:

```
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' \
    -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
    -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "devices": [
        {
            "device_id": "LightFixture00",
            "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00",
            "entity_type": "LightFixture",
            "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-JSON",
            "transport": "MQTT",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "name": "on",
                    "type": "command"
                },
                {
                    "name": "off",
                    "type": "command"
                }
            ],
            "static_attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "refPole",
                    "type": "Relationship",
                    "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Pole:0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

Sending the command through the IoT agent (works correctly):

```
curl -L -X PATCH 'http://localhost:4041/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00/attrs/on' \
    -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
    -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
        "type": "Property",
        "value": ""
}'
```

Sending the command to the context broker (Orion-LD):

```
curl -L -X PATCH 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00/attrs/on' \
-H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
        "type": "Property",
        "value": ""
}'
```

This does not work:

```
msg=***** ERROR Entity/Attribute not found: Entity 'urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00', Attribute 'on'
```

When I make the following request:

```
curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00' \
    -H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Contrary to what appears in this [tutorial](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent-json.html), I don't have the "on" and "off" commands and I suspect this is the reason for the above error:

```
{
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00",
    "type": "LightFixture",
    "refPole": {
        "object": "urn:ngsi-ld:Pole:0",
        "type": "Relationship",
        "observedAt": "2022-08-15T01:44:00.605Z"
    },
    "on_status": {
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandStatus",
            "@value": "OK"
        },
        "type": "Property",
        "observedAt": "2022-08-15T01:24:07.900Z"
    },
    "on_info": {
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandResult",
            "@value": ""
        },
        "type": "Property",
        "observedAt": "2022-08-15T01:24:07.900Z"
    },
    "off_status": {
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandStatus",
            "@value": "OK"
        },
        "type": "Property",
        "observedAt": "2022-08-15T01:44:00.605Z"
    },
    "off_info": {
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandResult",
            "@value": ""
        },
        "type": "Property",
        "observedAt": "2022-08-15T01:44:00.605Z"
    }
}
```

Context sources (`curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/csourceRegistrations' -H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot'`):

```
[
    {
        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:ContextSourceRegistration:...",
        "type": "ContextSourceRegistration",
        "endpoint": "http://iot-agent:4041",
        "information": [
            {
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00",
                        "type": "LightFixture"
                    }
                ],
                "properties": [
                    "on",
                    "off"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Edit**

After updating the IoT agent to the latest version ("1.24.0"), the request `curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00' -H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot` now returns the `on` and `off` commands:

```
{
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00",
    "type": "LightFixture",
    "refPole": {
        "type": "Relationship",
        "object": "urn:ngsi-ld:Pole:0",
    },
    "on_status": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandStatus",
            "@value": "UNKNOWN"
        }
    },
    "on_info": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandResult",
            "@value": " "
        }
    },
    "off_status": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandStatus",
            "@value": "UNKNOWN"
        }
    },
    "off_info": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "commandResult",
            "@value": " "
        }
    },
    "on": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "command",
            "@value": ""
        }
    },
    "off": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "command",
            "@value": ""
        }
    }
}
```

But I still get the same error:
`msg=***** ERROR Entity/Attribute not found: Entity 'urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00', Attribute 'on' (https://uri=etsi=org/ngsi-ld/default-context/on) (status code: 404)`

One thing that may be relevant - GET request output:

- In this [tutorial](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent-json.html):

```
    "on": {
        "type": "command",
        "value": ""
    },
    "off": {
        "type": "command",
        "value": ""
    }
```

- Mine:

```
    "on": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "command",
            "@value": ""
        }
    },
    "off": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "@type": "command",
            "@value": ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would be good to also see the registration between the broker and the iot-agent. And, important, do you start the broker with "-forwarding"?   (forwarding is costly and off by default - to avoid unnecessary lookups in the registrations collection)

Comment: @kzangeli Yes, I started the broker with the `-forwarding` option. I've updated the question with the context source registration. I only have `on_info`, `on_status`, `off_info`, `off_status` properties and I should also have `on` and `off` commands (as it appears in the tutorial), correct?

Comment: All looks good to me ... I've asked for help from out expert in iot-agents. I'm sure he'll be able to help

Comment: Can you  try provisioning using the following `fiware/orion-ld:1.1.0`
`mongo-db:4.4`, `fiware/iotagent-json:1.24.0-distroless` fixed docker images, set the debug to maximum and attach the relevant parts of the logs.

Comment: @kzangeli I have updated the IoT agent to version `1.24.0` and there has been "progress", but the error remains. I have updated the issue, please see.

Comment: @JasonFox I have updated the IoT agent to version `1.24.0` and there has been "progress", but the error remains. I have updated the issue, please see.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be `@context` related. Internally an NGSI-LD context broker holds all its attributes as expanded URIs. With a **GET** these are usually reduced to short names using a [compaction](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-api/#compaction) operation, so you see short attribute names, however when you **PATCH** you must be careful to supply the correct user `@context` as they payload is expanded prior to processing.

If you do `curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00'` and don't supply a user `@context` then the entity returned will expand all attributes.

As a check, you probably want to GET with and without your user context:

```bash
curl -iX GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00' \
    -H ''NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
    -H 'Link: <http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"'
```

This should return all attributes using short names.

```bash
curl -iX GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:LightFixture:00' \
    -H ''NGSILD-Tenant: openiot'
```

This should return all attributes using long URIs.

It could be the case that `"on"` has been previously been defined in your user `@context`. Now if you do a **PATCH** and don't supply the user `@context`, only the [core NGSI-LD @context](https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context-v1.5.jsonld) is processed. This contains the final line:

```
"@vocab": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/default-context/"
```

Which means that all unknown attributes are placed under `default-context/`. However, I assume that the term `"on"` has registered using a different URI, so that `https://uri=etsi=org/ngsi-ld/default-context/on` is not recognised as an attribute.

You can check the registrations using:

```bash
curl -G -iX GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/csourceRegistrations/' \
-H 'Accept: application/ld+json' \
-H 'Link: <http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
-d 'type=LightFixture'
```

When running an IoT Agent in NGSI-LD mode, you must supply a user `@context` - this is usually a Docker Environment variable:

```yaml
- "IOTA_JSON_LD_CONTEXT=http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld"
```

That is the user `@context` used to expand the entity attribute URIs, and is supplied with the registration of the command.

Obviously if you **omit** the `Link` header you can also check the expanded attributes:

```bash
curl -G -iX GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/csourceRegistrations/' \
-H 'Accept: application/ld+json' \
-d 'type=http://whatever/my/uri-is/LightFixture'
```

If something doesn't expand (like `Property`) is defined in core. If an **attribute** doesn't expand, it has fallen into the default context.

Comment: I'm using the default context - `IOTA_JSON_LD_CONTEXT=https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld` - and it's that context that is returned in GET requests (`-H 'Accept: application/ld+json'`). I never used the context header ("Link"). Anyway, I found that it works after all, that is, sending the command to Orion-LD triggers the sending of the MQTT command (topic ".../cmd") to the devices, but strangely, and despite the PATCH request return the code "204", the error still appears in the Orion-LD logs - "msg=***** ERROR Entity/Attribute not found: ...".